# Boostrap side toggle menu, close on clickout

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/ to add side menu to my website, but I want to add function to when clicked out the menu will be closed. Here is my code

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

     $("#page-content-wrapper").click(function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
        $("#menu-toggle").click();
        $(this).off(ev);
        });

    });


           });
    </script>
```

and try to do this way

```
 <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

     $("#page-content-wrapper").click(function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
         $(this).off(ev);
         console.log($("#wrapper"));
         if( $( "#wrapper" ).hasClass('.toggled') ) {
           $("#menu-toggle").click();
        }

        });

    });


           });
    </script>
```

But neither way show the result I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using below chunk of code **make sure your** `Body` or `Wrapper`'s height is `100%` to make this work otherwise it'll not fire any click event.

You just bind a click event on `Body` or parent `Div` and in that check clicked element is not id of menu `sidebar-wrapper` and Toogle button `menu-toggle`.

```
$('#wrapper').click(function(evt){
       if(evt.target.id == "sidebar-wrapper" || evt.target.id == "menu-toggle" )
          return false;
         $("#menu-toggle").click();     


});
```

**UPDATE**

Find Updated snippet

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
                   
    });
    
     $('#wrapper').click(function(evt){
       if(evt.target.id == "sidebar-wrapper" || evt.target.id == "menu-toggle" )
          return false;
        $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");   


   });
    

    
     
    
  
           });
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar (http://startbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */

 body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
```

Comment: this works first couple of clicks. but after 4-5 click page gets super slow, and hangs.I have try to put it both `   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
                    $('#wrapper').click(function(evt){
       if(evt.target.id == "sidebar-wrapper" || evt.target.id == "menu-toggle" )
          return false;
         $("#menu-toggle").click();
   });
    });
           });` and outside. When outside it side keeps being clickable

Comment: Oh paste  you html code as well so i can figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Looks good, thanks. If you update the answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out.. Anywhere you click on the document it checks whether or not you are clicking within the sidebar menu..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('#sidebar-wrapper').length === 0) {
            $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nLar6v3f/3/

Comment: I have try to click on the body, only Toggle Menu link works, I want to make whole side bar to be clickable

Comment: sidebar clickable to do what?

Answer (score 0):

It is your code , now check , its has working fine

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

     $("#page-content-wrapper").click(function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
         $(this).off(ev);
         console.log($("#wrapper"));
         if( $( "#wrapper" ).hasClass('toggled') ) {//  change the line [$( "#wrapper" ).hasClass('.toggled') ]
           $("#menu-toggle").click();
        }

        });

    });


           });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu-toggle', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    (<any>$('#wrapper.toggled').find("#sidebar-wrapper").find(".collapse")).collapse('hide');  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.